# Python SQL database parsing with a specific date range

Tags: python, sql, datetime, parsing

I would like to find a method to parse data in SQL database to only include a specified date range. We're working with clock-in/out machine database parsing; and soon it will become unworkable due to the sheer number of entries.

This is my script (written with community's help) to parse data:

```
for key in dictionary:
    regex = prefix + key
    f.write(dictionary.get(key) + '\n')  # header above each sub-list of clock-in formation
    with open(log_file_path, "r") as file:
        matched_list = re.findall(regex, file.read())  # parsing data from SQL database
        f.write(str(sorted(matched_list)))  # writing to a file
        f.write('\n' + '_' * 50 + '\n')
file.close()
```

...and the output is a list of entries written to a file under each person's ID:

```
'createTime: 2020-06-01T15:47:30.412Z\nemployee:\n  _id: id1, 
'createTime: 2020-06-01T19:29:39.708Z\nemployee:\n  _id: id1, 
'createTime: 2020-06-02T06:24:58.022Z\nemployee:\n  _id: id1,
```

Is there a way to add aditional functionality to allow for easy specification (let's say a string '2020-06-01'-'2020-06-03) to trim or exclude other entries which do not satisfy those dates:

So the entries are only generated in the range of, for instance, 2020-06-01 to 2020-06-03 inclusive.

I've got the script to generate the dates in Python using the datetime module. I thought I could generate a list to check against the each entry, and that didn't seemed to work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: You say you are parsing data in a SQL database, why arent you filtering using a SQL select?

Comment: as @TomC said, is there any reason why you are not sending a query to the SQL database, a ```SELECT``` and ```WHERE``` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately this is proprietary system and it does not permit us to do any changes or write queries. It processes the data internally and only the whole 'database download' option is available.

Comment: Strange, because its referred to as a SQL database, but the code looks like a simple file read. You would not have to write something in the database, you would be sending a query from your app. If you cant do you cant do, but if so then this is not a SQL question.